# How was this double sum simplified to a single sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I have to check a sum simplification of the following form:

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{k=-n}^{K-n} a_{k+n,n}b_k = \sum_{l=-\infty}^\infty \tilde{a}_l b_l $$

where $\tilde{a}_l$ is somehow related to the $a_{k+n,n}$. I don't know whether this is actually a correct transformation. So far I have not been able to find a sufficient explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $$\{(n,k): -\infty<n<\infty,~-n\le k \le K-n\} = \{(n,k): -\infty <k<\infty,~-k\le n \le K-k\}.$$

Assume the sum is absolute convergent, then one may change order of summation to obtain

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{k=-n}^{K-n} a_{k+n,n} b_k = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\left(\sum_{n=-k}^{K-k} a_{k+n,n}\right) b_k =:\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \tilde{a}_k b_k = \sum_{l=-\infty}^\infty \tilde{a}_l b_l
\end{align*}